# Django UTC Time Not Converting

Tags: django

Im unable to get the UTC time to convert to EST time.  I have successfully completed it in my servers shell, but when I do the exact same thing in my view it continues to print out the UTC time, not sure what Im missing.

```
views.py

from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

def today():
    today_utc = timezone.now()
    est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    return today_utc.astimezone(est)

def projections(request):
    todays_date = today()
    context = {'todays_date':todays_date}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and in my template i just do a simple {{todays_date}}, but it continues to print out UTC time.

Update:
Adding the timezone template tag fixes this, but I thought my function would take care of it.  Still interested to know what I did wrong....

```
{% load tz %}
{% timezone "US/Eastern" %}
    {{todays_date}}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timezone from `settings.py`.

```
USE_TZ = False

TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'
```

Comment: That would be a way to get times in US/Eastern always, but not a good approach to handling multiple timezones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the current timezone for the user to get times to convert. The [Django documentation provides an example middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) for doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
{{ todays_date|timezone:"America/New_York" }}
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/).